# Godot: How to limit player movement to certain tiles only?

Tags: game-engine, godot

I'm trying to make a '[Stone Age](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbUAM20ix8w)' clone.
And I'm trying to figure a way to limit my player movement to certain tiles. Meaning that a player can move only on certain tiles.

What I did so far is make two TileMaps one for 'walk-able floor' and one for 'un walk-able floor'. I put them on different collision layers and I have my player only collide with the 'un walk-able floor'. So the player is prevented from entering it:
Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHit5.png): The walkable floor is the brown tiles and the unwalkable are the ones that say 'FLOOR'.

This method is a problem because I have platforms I want to move my player on. (The tiles with the arrows on them) But If all the background is unwalkable, my player will collide with it when he'll be on a platform, so he won't be able to use the platforms to move...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution on [this](https://fornclake.com/2019/03/grid) guide and slightly modified it. In a nutshell the solution is to use [ray-cast](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) in the direction of the movement and see if there is a collision.

What I did was create a tilemap and call all the tiles that allow player movement 'walkable_[something]'. In the player script where I detect the collision from the ray cast I check the name of the tile the raycast collided with. If the name begins with 'walkable' I allow movement and in all other cases I don't.

```
onready var ray = $RayCast2D

var speed = 256 # big number because it's multiplied by delta
var tile_size = 64 # size in pixels of tiles on the grid

var last_position = Vector2() # last idle position
var target_position = Vector2() # desired position to move towards
var movedir = Vector2() # move direction

func _process(delta):
    # MOVEMENT
    if ray.is_colliding():
        var collision = ray.get_collider()
        if collision is TileMap:
            var tile_name = get_tile(collision)     
            if !(tile_name.begins_with("Walkable")):                
                position = last_position
                target_position = last_position
            else:
                position += speed * movedir * delta

                if position.distance_to(last_position) >= tile_size - speed * delta: # if we've moved further than one space
                    position = target_position # snap the player to the intended position


    else:
        position += speed * movedir * delta

        if position.distance_to(last_position) >= tile_size - speed * delta: # if we've moved further than one space
            position = target_position # snap the player to the intended position
```

This is the get_tile() function, it gets the string name of the tile the ray cast collided with. Because the raycast collision returns the **whole** tile map we need to know which specific tile we collided with. So I used the position of the player + the direction of the ray cast vector to figure out the correct tile. First I added half a tile in width and height of a tile size because the player position is considered the top left corner of the player node. For example if the player is a square of size 2x2 and he's positioned on (0,0). It means it's top left corner is on 0,0. Which means that 1,1 is the center of the square.

```
func get_tile(tile_map):    
    if tile_map is TileMap:
        var v = Vector2(tile_size / 2 , tile_size /2)
        var tile_pos = tile_map.world_to_map(position + v + ray.cast_to)
        var tile_id = tile_map.get_cellv(tile_pos)
        if (tile_id == -1):
            return "None"
        else:
            return tile_map.tile_set.tile_get_name(tile_id)
```

For the sake of completion [here](https://pastebin.com/kimj4g0x) is a pastebin of the full player script.